# Kotlin - Sort MutableList based on Object Property

Tags: list, sorting, kotlin

I have this Token Object:

```
class Token(type: TokenType, value: String, position: IntRange = 0..0)
```

I declare a MutableList:

```
val tokens: MutableList<Token> = mutableListOf()

// Mutable List filled
```

Now I want to sort my list based on the first value of the position IntRange. I tried doing this:

```
tokens
          .sortedBy { it.position.first }
```

However, I have no access to the object after using the it keyword, so position is highlighted red.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21):

Another observation is that `sortedBy` returns a sorted copy of the list. If you want to sort your mutable list in place, you should use `sortBy` function:

```
tokens.sortBy { it.position.first } 
// tokens is sorted now
```

Comment: Also, use a `sortByDescending` for the reversed sort!

Answer (score 3):

The `position` is a [parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#parameters) rather than a [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#properties-and-fields), to make it to a [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#properties-and-fields) on the [primary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) by `val`/`var` keyword, for example:

```
//makes the parameter to a property by `val` keyword---v
class Token(val type: TokenType,  val value: String,  val position:IntRange = 0..0)
```

**THEN** you can sort your `Token`s by the `position`, for example:

```
tokens.sortedBy { it.position.first }
```

Comment: oh, dumb mistake. Thank you :)

Comment: @Rechunk Not at all. it is my pleasure, :)

Answer (score 3):

try with sortBy method,

```
val result = tokens.sortBy { it.position }
```